# What if executeFetchRequest returns 1 item of type: NSKnownKeysDictionary1 instead of managedObjectContext

Tags: core-data, save, nsfetchrequest

I have working code that receives a web service of updates, makes the decision to update or create a new, but the update is not working. (I have read dozens of other questions here, including one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571786/how-to-update-existing-object-in-core-data) that is what I am following. Another example is the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520559/core-data-how-update-a-record?rq=1))

The saveContext: below executes without error and without query (using Debug level 2)

The returned array with 19 as the desired record. From `po results`:

```
<_PFArray 0xa349280>(
{
    address = "an address";
    companyName = "the Name";
    email = "email@company.com";
    fname = "first name";
    inserted = "2014-05-01 04:00:00 +0000";
    level = 3;
    lname = "last name";
    num = 19;
    phone = "phone #";
    tax2 = "tax number";
}
```

To summarize:

1. No query to Core Data is being performed at saveContext
2. No errors are being thrown in debugger or by saveContext
3. Changes are NOT being saved to Core Data
4. The `results` array is a _PFArray
5. I think the issue is with the `existingObject` object. It is not correctly referencing the managedObjectContext.

What do I need to have the saveContext save the data?

** EDIT: ** I have narrowed this down to the `existObject` NOT being the correct type, but am still looking for the reason it isn't a `managedObjectContext`.

Here is the fetch method. Maybe the issue is in here:

```
- (NSArray *)performFetchInEntity:(NSString *)entity withPredicate:(NSString *)predicate {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;

    // Create the fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entity
                                         inManagedObjectContext:context]];

    // This next line should NOT be used !!!
    // [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    if (predicate)
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicate]];

    // Execute the fetch.
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                             error:&error];

    NSLog(@"returned: %@", [result objectAtIndex:0]);
    if (!error)
        return result;
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Comment: You've verified that at least some of the values on the object have changed and need to be updated, I assume?

Comment: @TomHarrington Yes. This part of the project started with your 'Saving JSON to Core Data' on cimg. To expound, I am have adapted your code, because I may have updates to 5 entities coming in the json.

Comment: @TomHarrington At this moment, the verify is printing the result array (one item) and seeing existObject's value and key pass through with the desired changes. No change is being made, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the culprit:

```
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

Removing that line caused the type to correctly be returned in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

I was getting the error: **NSKnownKeysDictionary1**  unknown object.

I was trying to fetch Array of Object from Core Data and i wrote line of code in method:

```
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName]];
sortByName =nil;
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

Than I was trying to get object from Array using fast enumaration.
It was trowing the error. NSKnownKeysDictionary1 unknown object.
I removed the

```
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

Code worked.